# Target closest div of a certain class with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling with how to correctly apply .closest

A series of inputs are being used to record the score of a set of tennis.
If a user inputs a 7-6 or 6-7 combination, a hidden div appears so they can record the tiebreak.

I only want the hidden tiebreak div that's closest to the current inputs to appear.

Here's what i have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                var div = $('.tiebreakfield');
                $('.score1, .score2').keyup(function() {
                    var value1 = parseInt($(".score1").val());
                    var value2 = parseInt($(".score2").val()); 
                   if ((value1 == 6 || value1 == 7) && (value2 == 6 || value2 == 7) && (value1 !== value2)) {
                        div.fadeIn();
                    } else {
                        div.fadeOut();   
                    }
                });
            });

$(document).ready(function() {
                var div = $('.tiebreakfield');
                $('.score3, .score4').keyup(function() {
                    var value1 = parseInt($(".score3").val());
                    var value2 = parseInt($(".score4").val()); 
                   if ((value1 == 6 || value1 == 7) && (value2 == 6 || value2 == 7) && (value1 !== value2)) {
                        div.fadeIn();
                    } else {
                        div.fadeOut();   
                    }
                });
            });
```

The code above shows all hidden divs if the 7-6 combo is inputted.

Here's an example...http://jsfiddle.net/jQHDR/

Comment: you dont _need_ 2 `ready` events (just a sidenote)

Comment: Where exactly are you using .closest?

Comment: Your code doesn't have hidden tiebreak div, not even in the fiddle ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it didnt work was because you werent referring to the correct `p.tiebreakfield`. You could either go to `.score` from the `input` and `next()` will take you to `p` :

```
$(this).parent(".score").next("p");
```

or you could go to the super parent (parent of parent) and iterate back to the `p` :

```
$(this).closest("div").find(".tiebreakfield");
```

And you could largely reduce your code to a smaller way like this :

```
//find all text boxes which have a class that start with "score"; this will apply to score-n inputs
$('input[class^="score"]').keyup(function () {
    //find the nearest p.tiebreakfield
    var div = $(this).closest("div").find(".tiebreakfield");
    //get an array of inputs
    var inputs = $(this).parent().find("input[type=text]");
    //first value of text box group
    var value1 = parseInt(inputs[0].value);
    //second value of text box group
    var value2 = parseInt(inputs[1].value);
    //your condition checking
    var isShow = ["6,7", "7,6"].indexOf(value1 + "," + value2) !== -1;
    if (isShow) {
        //your actions
        div.fadeIn();
    } else {
        //your actions again
        div.fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/jQHDR/4/

**Things I changed in your code :**

1. Removed the extra DOM `ready` events.
2. Joined up all the event handlers and used the **starts with selector** of jQuery.
3. set up `div` variable *inside* the event
4. got an array of inputs in and around keyup triggered input. (To generalise the score inputs) so that it can be used for getting values later.
5. Insted of the complex `if..else` loop i made the condition checking using `indexOf`. It will return `-1` if the condition isn't satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

1. You dont need 2 `ready()`.
2. Element with class `.tiebreakfield` is not a `div`.

If i good understanded you problem then I think that this is an example of a code that you needs:

```
                $('.score1, .score2').keyup(function() {
                var element = $(this).parent().siblings(".tiebreakfield");
                var value1 = parseInt($(".score1").val());
                var value2 = parseInt($(".score2").val()); 
               if ((value1 == 6 || value1 == 7) && (value2 == 6 || value2 == 7) && (value1 !== value2)) {
                    element .fadeIn();
                } else {
                    element .fadeOut();   
                }
            });
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/vTQr6/

Comment: `div` is just a variable name. I know it doesnt sound right, but its not invalid or something